# User process shadows mysqld service, how do I find the bad command?

Tags: mysql, service, authentication, mariadb, startup

Kubuntu 17

When I login and do "ps -ef | grep mysqld" I see two copies running, one as the system service daemon, and one as a user process.

```
ps -ef | grep mysqld
mysql     1953     1  0 09:02 ?        00:00:13 /usr/sbin/mysqld
richard   3233  3220  0 09:13 ?        00:00:35 /usr/sbin/mysqld --
defaults-file=/home/richard/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --
datadir=/home/richard/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --
socket=/tmp/akonadi-richard.EK3Z9U/mysql.socket
richard  13309  3138  0 18:05 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 
mysqld
```

I don't see any script or command with "mysqld" in ~/.profle, ~/.autostart, ~/.bashrc,  /etc/profile, /etc/init.d (except for the mysql start script presumably used by the system and owned by root.

Where else should I look for the errant command?
Any great ideas on *how* to look for it effectively?

Comment: Are you sure this is an "errant" process, and not merely something legitmate that you aren't expecting...
such as [akonadi](https://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi) running it's own independent copy of the MySQL Server daemon to keep its data?  That's certainly what it looks like.

Comment: [*"Akonadi starts its own local MySQL server."*](https://techbase.kde.org/KDE_PIM/Akonadi#Why_not_use_sqlite.3F)

Comment: It was annoying when mariadb failed to update.  I'll keep an eye on it and if things act strangely, I'll be back with more questions.

Thanks for the info.  akonadi is a black hole to me.